# SQL Server Agent Job Not Reading SSIS Project Parameters

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I have an SQL Server Agent Job running a number of SSIS Packages via a series of steps. The packages themselves are set up to read source and destination server locations via a query to an SQL config table. However, the  initial connection pointing to the config table has a hardcoded server location.

When rolling out the SSIS Packages and Agent Job from test to stage, I will need to alter the hardcoded location of the config table from the old test location, to the new stage location. I thought a way around this would be to create a Project Parameter for the location of the config table, and feed each package connection for the config table with this variable, meaning I'd only have to change this Project Param, rather than manually alter the connection in each package.

This works fine if I execute the package in visual studio, but an agent job is unable to read the project parameter, and the step fails.

Does anybody know of a way around this? I've done some reading on SSIS Environment Variables, but as far as I can see this wouldn't solve the problem. I've also been told that I can specify connection properties in the command line of the agent job itself, but I haven't been able to get this to override a package variable.

If anyone has an ideas it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added this to the command line of the job, immediately after /CHECKPOINTING OFF:

```
/SET "\"\Package.Variables[VARIABLENAME].Properties[Value]\"";VARIABLEVALUE
```